# Extend ActiveRecord aliases to find_by_ methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In an `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass, I want to alias a field because in new classes there is an equivalent field with a different name. For example, I do something like:

```
class OldClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :new_style_id, :id
end
class NewClass < ActiveRecord::Base ; end
```

`new_style_id`, being a field on `NewClass`, has a finder like `find_by_new_style_id`, but `alias_attribute` doesn't create a similar finding for `OldClass`, thus trying to call `find_by_new_style_id` raises an undefined method exception when called on `OldClass`. Short of simply adding `find_by_new_style_id` to `OldClass`, is there a way to have Rails automatically generate the finder for the alias so that both `OldClass` and `NewClass` will respond to `find_by_new_style_id`?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a scope:

```
scope : find_by_new_style_id, -> (new_style_id){ where( 'style_id=?', new_style_id ) }
```

If you need to use it in more than one class, you can use a concern.

```
module StyleScope
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    scope : find_by_new_style_id, -> (new_style_id){ where( 'style_id=?', new_style_id ) }
  end
end
```

And in your models:

```
ìnclude StyleScope
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope

Comment: while that's a solution, i'm not sure it's really better than what i've done for now, which is just implement `find_by_new_style_id` myself like `def find_by_new_style_id(id) ; find_by_id(id) ; end` on `OldClass`.

Comment: You can have a look to this article: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/